# Генератор случайных чисел

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, range

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать свой генератор случайных чисел, то есть класс Random исключаем.
Кое-что реализовал, вот код:

```
function getRandonNumber() {
    var now = new Date(); // берем текущую дату и время

    var hours = now.getHours(); // Извлекаем часы 
    var minutes = now.getMinutes(); // Извлекаем минуты 
    var seconds = now.getSeconds(); // Извлекаем секунды клики
    var milliseconds = (hours * 3600000) + (minutes * 60000) + (seconds * 1000) + now.getMilliseconds(); // Получаем миллисекунды 

    
    var result = milliseconds % 100;
    document.getElementById("for-word").innerHTML = "Случайное число: " + result;
}
```

Данные метод генерирует случайное число от 0 до 99. Сейчас я не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы числа были в диапазоне от 15 до 99. Как это сделать?

Comment: `% 85 + 15` . .

Comment: Ну и вообще `var milliseconds = Date.now()` и к случайным числам это как-то не очень имеет отношение

Comment: вообще-то миллисекунды это new Date().getTime();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
function getRandonNumber() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var result = now % 85 + 15;
    console.log("Случайное число: " + result);
}
```

```html
<button id="random" onClick="return getRandonNumber();">get random</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно что-нибудь такое изобразить)

```js
function getRandom() {
  const m = 4294967296;
  let value;
  
  const gen = () => value = (64525 * value + 1013904223) % m;
  gen.seed = v => value = v % m;

  gen.seed(Date.now());
  return gen;
}

const getRandomNumber = getRandom();
const getRandomInt = (min, max) => getRandomNumber() % (max-min+1) + min;



// Генерация 25 чисел
const lst = []
for (let i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
  lst.push(getRandomInt(15, 99))
}
console.log(lst.join());

// Демонстрация приемлемой равномерности =)
const map = {}
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  const r = getRandomInt(15, 99);
  map[r] = (map[r] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(map);

// Демонстрация посева зерна
let same = [], seed = Date.now();
getRandomNumber.seed(seed); same.push(getRandomInt(1, 100));
getRandomNumber.seed(seed); same.push(getRandomInt(1, 100));
getRandomNumber.seed(seed); same.push(getRandomInt(1, 100));
console.log(same.join());
```